# How to remove loading icon from azure media player

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am developing a site where i need to integrate "Azure media player" and i have a functionality that to render the video from where the user is already paused.

My issue is that, while resume the video a loading icon is appears in the player and which is not disappears when user start playing the video.

I am attaching my html and js code for rendering the player.Due to some security reasons i am attaching only the demo code.

```
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    amp.options.flashSS.swf = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf"
    amp.options.flashSS.plugin = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-osmf2.0.swf"
    amp.options.silverlightSS.xap = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/SmoothStreamingPlayer.xap"
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        displayVideo();
    });

    function displayVideo() {
        var myOptions = {
            techOrder: ["Flash","azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"],
            nativeControlsForTouch: false,
            autoplay: false,
            controls: true,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            poster: "",
            logo: { "enabled": false },
            hotKeys: { "enableFullscreen": true, "enableNumbers": true, "enableJogStyle": true, "enableMute": true, "seekStep": 3, "volumeStep": 5 },
        };
        var myPlayer = amp("moduleVideoPlayer", myOptions, function () {
        });

        myPlayer.addEventListener('ready', function () {
            console.log('ready!');
        });


        myPlayer.addEventListener("durationchange", function () {
            var duration = myPlayer.duration();
            if (duration > 0) {
                myPlayer.currentTime(8);
            }
        });


        myPlayer.addEventListener('ended', function () {
            console.log('Finished!');
        });

        myPlayer.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            //alert(this.currentTime());
            console.log('paused!');
        });

        myPlayer.src([
          {
              src: "//amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest",
              type: "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml",
              streamingFormats: ['SMOOTH']
              //streamingFormats: ["SMOOTH", "DASH", "HLS-V3", "HLS-V4"]
          },
        ]);
    }
</script>

<div style="width:500px;height:300px;margin-top:50px;">
    <video id="moduleVideoPlayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered"> </video>
</div>
```

***Note:***
I am encoding the asset in **"H264 Smooth Streaming 720p"** format.

Please give a solution for this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Also, kind of curious as to your techOrder -> the recommended techOrder is (and defaulted) techOrder: ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"] you should remove "Flash". This is to allow the best possible playback on the most popular browsers and devices.

And when setting the source, why are you forcing Smooth? The recommended streamingFormat (and default) is ["DASH", "SMOOTH", "HLS-V4", "HLS-V3"].  This is to allow the best possible playback on the most popular browsers and devices.

Is there a reason you are doing the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the spinner is shown via css so you can just hide the spinner element based on the class `<div tabindex="-1" class="vjs-loading-spinner"></div>`